# When I create a user in the Magento admin, it automatically unsubscribes them from Mailchimp

Tags: extensions, customer

Obviously this only happens if that user has previously subscribed to our mailing list, and yes we have the MageMonkey extension.

Has anyone encountered something like this before? I'm guessing it automatically sets the user NOT part of the newsletter (in magento), and that information gets sent to Mailchimp because the unsubscribe happens immediately on creation of the user. And there's no way to set the Newsletter before creating the user.

Please feel free to simply respond with Mailchimp alternatives, as well.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I figured out this was caused by the fact that I also use Mandrill (Mailchimp's email delivery system) to send our welcome emails (and all magento transactional emails). Because I did not have an unsubscribe link in my welcome email (which is against mailchimp's agreement), they went ahead and auto-unsubscribed the users from my mailchimp mailing list.

Here is a link for reference:

http://ebizmarts.com/forums/topics/view/6452